# Find two vector b such that Ab = b

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I have a question which I am unable to solve.

I have this matrix:

$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 4 & 8\\
1 & 3 & 9 & 27
\end{bmatrix}
$

I have to find two vector $\bf{b}$ such that $A\bf{b}=\bf{b}$

I know that the vector $0$ is one of the answer but I don't know how to find a non zero vector.

Is it possible for you to lead me in the right direction and help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 4 & 8\\
1 & 3 & 9 & 27
\end{bmatrix}
$

Let $
b = \begin{bmatrix}
 p \\
q \\
r \\
s 
\end{bmatrix}
$

Then,we get

$
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 4 & 8\\
1 & 3 & 9 & 27
\end{bmatrix}
$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
 p \\
q \\
r \\
s 
\end{bmatrix}
$
=$
\begin{bmatrix}
 p \\
q \\
r \\
s 
\end{bmatrix}
$

You will get equations as

$-q+r-s=0$

$p+r+s=0$

$p+2q+3r+8s=0$

$p+3q+9r+26s=0$

Solve the equations and find unknowns

It has trivial solution i.e $p=q=r=s=0$

Hence $
 b = \begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}
$

Answer (score 2):

If $Ab = b$, then $(A-\mathbb{I})b = 0$, so find the nullspace of 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 8 \\
1 & 3 & 9 & 26\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: null space of matrix contains only zero vector

Comment: @rst If you prove that the nullspace of this matrix has only the zero vector, then you have shown that no nonzero $b$ satisfies $Ab = b$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Construct a system of four equations in four unknowns, where the unknowns are the components of $\mathbf{b}$.